# What is Google Sheets script equivalent of Excel VBA's UsedRange

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

In Excel VBA I can loop through the cells of a worksheet but I can optimize this loop by only looping through the worksheet's UsedRange.  UsedRange is a rectangle that encompasses all cells that contain something (value, formula, text etc.) or have done previously and are now empty.

Essentially, the [UsedRange](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.usedrange) encompasses every cell that has been touched.

UsedRange does not appear in the [list of methods for a Google Sheet](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet)

Is UsedRange called something different in the Google Sheets world or is it just missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get the range of cells that encompasses all values in a sheet, use [Sheet.getDataRange()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#getdatarange).